# Show a UIViewController when she stop loading (webViewDidFinishLoad) in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have one `UIViewController` subclass called `ThemeView`. When I click on 1 button, it initiates an instance of a second `UIViewController` subclass called `ViewJeuSolo` and displays it.

```
-(IBAction) boutonJouer:(id)sender{

    //Do something

    ViewJeuSolo *secondViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewJeuSolo"];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

}
```

So this works. My issue: there is a `WebView` in `ViewJeuSolo` and I want to show a spinner, load the `WebView` and after that do the

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

I already have a

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wva
```

But I can't see how to connect this function to my previous view.

Summary: I want to switch view only when the WebView in the new view has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who have the same issue,i do this:

Put all the fonction for load the webview in you're first view. When you need to change view, load the web view in hidde and show the spinner. When the web view was load, init the next view and give the webview by a setwebview() function.

Is work fine for me :).
If you need more precision, tell me.
Thanks all for you're help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible - you are going to have to load the `UIWebView` based view (here `secondViewController`) and then display the "Please Wait" loading message until the delegate `webViewDidFinishLoad` is called.

One thing you could do is to present a `UIView` based loading screen from `secondViewController` and then remove it once the delegate method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you said you already have this `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wva` in your sub-class `ViewJeuSolo`. So why do not you just set `BOOL` variable inside this method. And when loading has been finsished then it will come to your this line `[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];`. So before that only did you check like this ?

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wva
{
self.isloaded=YES; //declare insatance variable as bool
}

-(IBAction) boutonJouer:(id)sender{

    //Do something

    ViewJeuSolo *secondViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewJeuSolo"];

//now check here you bool variable value
if (secondViewController.isloaded==YES)
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
secondViewController.isloaded=NO;
}
}
```

Comment: Yep i think about something like this but the - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wva function is in the ViewJeuSolo, so the view i try to load. So this doen't work :)

Comment: i mean are you not able to loading the view?? This is the problem??

Comment: I mean i'm can't change the view when the webView in the next view tell she finish load.